# An integro-differential equation arising in solving a 2nd-order O.D.E.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integro-differential-equations

I’d like to solve the O.D.E.:

$$(1+\Phi_{x})\,\Phi_{xx}=\left(-1+\sqrt{1+\Phi^2}\right)\Phi,$$

where $\Phi=\Phi(x)$, $x\in(-1,1)$. It can be written as

$$
\frac{\Bbb d}{\Bbb dx}\left(\Phi_{x}+\frac{1}{2}\Phi_{x}^2\right)=\left(-1+\sqrt{1+\Phi^2}\right)\Phi,
$$
which leads to
$$
\Phi_{x}^2+2\,\Phi_{x}-\int_{-1}^{x}f\big(\Phi(t)\big)\,\Bbb dt=0
$$
where $f\big(\Phi(t)\big)=2\left(-1+\sqrt{1+\Phi^2(t)}\right)\Phi(t)$.
This gives
$$
\Phi_{x}=-1+\sqrt{1+\int_{-1}^{x}f\big(\Phi(t)\big)\,\Bbb dt}.
$$
In other words, we obtain an integro-differential equation. Any idea to start with proving the existence of solutions (numerically or analytically)? Or it is easier to directly deal with the original nonlinear 2nd-order O.D.E. (an exact solution is available)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(1+\frac{\Bbb d\Phi}{\Bbb dx}\right)\frac{\Bbb d^2\Phi}{\Bbb dx^2}=\left(-1+\sqrt{1+\Phi^2}\right)\Phi$$
Let $\frac{\Bbb d\Phi}{\Bbb dx}=F(\Phi)$ then $\frac{\Bbb d^2\Phi}{\Bbb dx^2}=\frac{\Bbb dF}{\Bbb d\Phi}\frac{\Bbb d\Phi}{\Bbb dx}=\frac{\Bbb dF}{\Bbb d\Phi}F(\Phi)$
$$(1+F)F\frac{\Bbb dF}{\Bbb d\Phi}=\left(-1+\sqrt{1+\Phi^2}\right)\Phi$$
This can be integrated:
$$\frac{1}{2}F^2+\frac{1}{3}F^3=\int\left(-1+\sqrt{1+\Phi^2}\right)\Phi \Bbb d\Phi$$
A particular solution of $(1+F)F\frac{\Bbb dF}{\Bbb d\Phi}=\left(-1+\sqrt{1+\Phi^2}\right)\Phi$ is:
$$F=-1+\sqrt{1+\Phi^2}$$
$\frac{\Bbb d\Phi}{\Bbb dx}=-1+\sqrt{1+\Phi^2}$
$$x=\int \frac{\Bbb d\Phi}{-1+\sqrt{1+\Phi^2}}=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+\Phi^2}}{\Phi}-\sinh^{-1}(\Phi)+C$$
This doesn’t provide all the solutions.

Comment: Thanks so much for providing this idea. Indeed, It works. About the integration
$$\int(-1+\sqrt{1+\Phi^2})\Phi d\Phi,$$

it seems to be $\frac{1}{3} \left(\Phi^2+1\right)^{3/2}-\frac{\Phi^2}{2}$?

Comment: You are right. This is an obvious mistake : I forgot the $\Phi$ in the integral. So, the end of my answer is deleted.